# Spring Reactive - collect a sequence of paged results as a Mono of all results

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

In my REST service I must call another REST service multiple times to get all the pages of the result list. The request contains a `from` field which I need to increase with every request. The response contains a `totalResults` field - when I've read all results I need to stop calling the other service, collect all the results from all calls and produce one `Mono<List<Result>>` response.

This is what I had so far:

```
@Getter
public class Request {
    private int from;
    private int size = 1000;
    private String type;

    public Request(String type, int from) {
        this.type = type;
        this.from = from;
    }
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class Response {
    private Integer totalResults;
    private Integer size;
    private Integer from;
    private List<Result> results;
}

public Mono<List<Result>> findByType(String type) {
    return Flux.generate(
            () -> new Request(type, 0),
            (Request request, SynchronousSink<List<Result>> sink) -> {
                Response response = find(request).block();
                sink.next(response.getResults());
                int nextFrom = response.getFrom() + response.getSize();
                if (nextFrom >= response.getTotalResults()) {
                    sink.complete();
                }
                return new Request(type, nextFrom);
            })
            .flatMap(Flux::fromIterable)
            .collectList();
}

private Mono<Response> find(Request request) {
    return webClient
            .post()
            .uri("/search")
            .syncBody(request)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Response.class);
}
```

It works in a test using `MockWebServer` and `StepVerifier` but fails in production with

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-2
```

How can I do it the correct reactive way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***EDIT*** with help of Adam, the `expand` functionfixes this issue

```
public Mono<List<Result>> findByType(Request request) {
        return find(request)
                .expand(response -> {
                    int nextFrom = response.getFrom() + response.getSize();
                    if (nextFrom >= response.getTotalResults()) {
                        return Mono.empty();
                    }
                    return find(new Request(request.getType(), response.getFrom() + response.getSize()));
                })
                 .flatMap(response -> Flux.fromIterable(response.getResults()))
                 .collectList();;
    }

    private Mono<Response> find(Request request) {
        return webClient
                .post()
                .uri("/search")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .syncBody(request)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Response.class);
    }
```

Comment: I used the same approach but in my case expand is not terminating